# libav : deinsterlace option?

Tags: video, video-conversion, libav

I have compiled from GIT sources the `libav` 2014-march-10.

On usual `libav` from Ubuntu repositories, I was able to use `-deinterlace` to... well, deinterlace the video. Now this option appears to be missing.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **deinterlace** option is now deprecated (see this [git commit](http://patches.libav.org/patch/36295/)):

> Patchwork ffmpeg: Replace -deinterlace (which was broken by the buffer
>   ref stuff) with yadif injection

You have to use **yadif** to deinterlace the input video (yadif means "*yet another deinterlacing filter*").

Visit [libav.org](http://libav.org/avconv.html#yadif) for further details about **yadif**

---

In short, you will have to add `-filter:v yadif` to your command-line.

Comment: Looks like libav is missing most of the other deinterlacing filters from ffmpeg like the latest addition of [w3fdif](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#w3fdif). I'd recommend  installing ffmpeg from the PPA listed on the FFmpeg project page, as the new filter seems to produce good quality.

Comment: Thanks to Sylvain, I was able to use `-filter:v yadif` to my command and now it works. But it's quite buggy = it works on MPEG-2 intrelaced input file, but it's buggy for other input files (like mp4) I've tried.